# Remove duplicate elements from a list in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang

How can I remove the duplicate from a list in Erlang?

Suppose I have a list like:

```
[1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6]
```

How can I get:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: Is input list already sorted?

Comment: And does order matter? May I reorder the elements?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could use `sets`, for example:

```
my_nonDuplicate_list1() ->
    List = [1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6],
    Set = sets:from_list(List),
    sets:to_list(Set).
```

This returns `[1,2,3,4,5]`, no more duplicates, but most likely not sorted.

Another possibility without the usage of `sets` would be:

```
my_nonDuplicate_list2() ->
    List = [1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6],
    lists:usort(List).
```

In this case it returns `[1,2,3,4,5]`, no more duplicates and sorted.

Comment: how efficient is this underneath the covers? I presume the `usort` is N log N, is the sets linear? I imagine going from a list to a set is linear, and also visa versa, so maybe the first option is more efficient (if sorting is not needed).

Answer (score 19):

And for those looking to preserve the order of the list:

```
remove_dups([])    -> [];
remove_dups([H|T]) -> [H | [X || X <- remove_dups(T), X /= H]].
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the gist of wanting a `distinct` or `remove_dups` function for a list is to preserve the order, otherwise using sets or ordered sets is always an option.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution that will `Preserve the order of the elements` to help you learn how to manipulate lists, would involve two functions:

```
delete_all(Item, [Item | Rest_of_list]) ->
    delete_all(Item, Rest_of_list);
delete_all(Item, [Another_item| Rest_of_list]) ->
    [Another_item | delete_all(Item, Rest_of_list)];
delete_all(_, []) -> [].

remove_duplicates(List)-> removing(List,[]). 
removing([],This) -> lists:reverse(This);
removing([A|Tail],Acc) -> 
    removing(delete_all(A,Tail),[A|Acc]).
```

To test,

```
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
1> mymod:remove_duplicates([1,2,3,1,2,4,1,2,1]).
[1,2,3,4]
2>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this at first to preserve order, though it is **not recommended**. Remember that `AddedStuff ++ Accumulator` is OK but `Accumulator ++ AddedStuff` is really bad.

```
rm_dup(List) ->
    lists:foldl(
        fun(Elem, Acc) ->
            case lists:member(Elem, Acc) of
                true ->
                    Acc;
                false ->
                    Acc ++ [Elem]
            end
        end, [], List
    ).
```

This solution is much more efficient if you want to preserve order:

```
rm_dup(List) ->
    lists:reverse(lists:foldl(
        fun(Elem, Acc) ->
            case lists:member(Elem, Acc) of
                true ->
                    Acc;
                false ->
                    [Elem] ++ Acc
            end
        end, [], List
    )).
```

Answer (score 0):

Module `sets` has two functions that can be composed and do the job in an efficient way: `sets:from_list/1` returns a set with all the elements of a list (with no duplicated elements from definition) and `sets:to_list/1` returns a list with the elements of a set. Here is an example of use:

```
4> sets:to_list(sets:from_list([1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6])).
[3,6,2,5,1,4]
```

We could define the function as

```
nub(L) -> sets:to_list(sets:from_list(L)).
```

Comment: Please add clarification to your answer

Answer (score 0):

for my opinion, the best option is to use `lists:usort()`

But in case you don't want to use BIF's, and you want the list to be sorted, I suggest a version of quick sort, in this implementation you will get the list sorted without duplicate values.

```
unique_sort([]) -> [];
unique_sort([Pivot|T]) ->
unique_sort ([X || X <- T, X < Pivot ) ]++
[Pivot] ++
unique_sort ([X || X <- T, X > Pivot ]).
```